# Delete text if its not "X" "Y" or "Z"

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word, delete-row

I am looking to delete all of the text in a document that is not matching a criteria.

The text is found here:

https://www.mnsu.edu/supersite/academics/catalogs/undergraduate/2014-2015/2014-2015-undergraduate-bulletin.pdf

For example it would delete most of everything up to page 14. On page 15 it would leave behind "PRE-MORTUARY SCIENCE ACCT 200 BIOL 220" and so on.

I have been trying:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithSpecifiedText()
    Dim sText As String

    sText = InputBox("Enter text for Row to be deleted")
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = sText
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

This throws

> error 5941: "The requested member of the collection does not exist".

I set up a list of everything I want to keep in the document at the bottom of this post.

I also want to delete the row if it doesn't match the generic form of the class ID:
"XX ###" or "XXX ###" or "XXXX ###"

"ACCT"*"AIS"*"ANTH"*"ART"*"AST"*"AET"*"AVIA"*"BIOL"*"BLAW"*"CAHN"*"CHEM"*"CHIN"*"CIVE"*"BUS"*"CDIS"*"CMST"*"CM"*"CS"*"CORR"*"CSP"*"DAK"*"DANC"*"DHYG"*"ECON"*"ED"*"EDLD"*"EEC"*"KSP"*"EE"*"EET"*"ENG"*"ESL"*"EAP"*"ENVR"*"ETHN"*"EXED"*"FILM"*"FCS"*"FINA"*"FYEX"*"FREN"*"GWS"*"GEOG"*"GEOL"*"GER"*"GERO"*"HLTH"*"HIST"*"HONR"*"HP"*"HUM"*"IT"*"ENGR"*"IEP"*"IBUS"*"IPO"*"IDST"*"LAWE"*"MGMT"*"MET"*"MRKT"*"MASS"*"MACC"*"MBA"*"MATH"*"ME"*"MEDT"*"MSL"*"MDSM"*"MUSE"*"MUSC"*"MUSP"*"NPL"*"NURS"*"PYIL"*"PHYS"*"POL"*"PSYC"*"RPLS"*"REHB"*"SCAN"*"SOST"*"SOWK"*"SOC"*"SPAN"*"SPED"*"STAT"*"THEA"*"URBS"*"WCDP"*"WLC"*"1"*"2 "*"3"*"4"*"5"*"6"*"7"*"8"*"9"*"0"

% Pre-Professional Programs % Pre-Chiropractic % Pre-Dental % Pre-Engineering % Pre-Law % Pre-Medicine % Pre-Mortuary Science % Pre-Occupational Therapy % Pre-Optometry % Pre-Osteopathic Medicine and Surgery % Pre-Pharmacy % Pre-Physical Therapy % Pre-Podiatric Medicine and Surgery % Pre-Veterinary Medicine % Academic Colleges % Advising/General Education/Diverse Cultures/Writing Intensive % Academic Programs % Accounting % Aging Studies (Formally Gerontology) % Alcohol and Drug Studies % Allied Health and Nursing (Intro Course) % American Indian Studies % Anthropology % Applied Organizational Studies % Art % Astronomy % Athletic Coaching % Athletic Training % Automotive Engineering Technology % Aviation % Biochemistry % Biology % Biotechnology % Business Administration % Business Education % Business Law % Chemistry % Chinese (Mandarin) % Civil Engineering % Cognitive Science % Communication Disorders % Communication Studies % Computer Engineering % Computer Engineering Technology % Computer Information Technology % Computer Science % Construction Management % Corporate & Community Fitness/Wellness % Corrections % Counseling and Student Personnel % Dance % Dental Hygiene % Earth Science % Economics % Educational Leadership % Electrical Engineering % Electronic Engineering Technology % Elementary Education % English % English for Non-Native Speakers (English As A Second Language) % Environmental Sciences % Ethnic Studies % Exercise Science % Family Consumer Science % Film Studies % Finance % First Year Experience % Food Science Technology % French % Gender and Women’s Studies % Geography % Geology % German % Health Science % History % Honors % Humanities % Human Performance % Information Systems % Iron Range Engineering % Integrated Engineering % Interdisciplinary Studies % International Business % International Relations % Japanese % Latin % Latin American Studies % Law Enforcement % Liberal Studies % Management % Manufacturing Engineering Technology % Marketing % Mass Media % Mathematics % Mechanical Engineering % Medical Laboratory Science % Military Science and Leadership/Army ROTC % Museum Studies (See Anthropology) % Music % Nonprofit Leadership % Norwegian % Nursing % Philosophy % Philosophy, Politics, and Economics (PPE) % Physics % Political Science % Portuguese % Psychology % Recreation, Parks & Leisure Services % Rehabilitation Counseling % Russian % Scandinavian Studies % Science Teaching % Secondary % - % & K- % Education—Professional Education % Social Studies % Social Work % Sociology % Spanish % Special Education: Academic & Behavioral Strategist % Sport Management % Statistics % Swedish % Teaching English As A Second Language (TESL) % Theatre Arts % Twin Cities Engineering % Urban & Regional Studies % World Languages & Cultures %

Answer (score 0):

`Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` will return `True` if the selection is inside a table. `If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` will therefore only be executed if the item found is **not** in a table. However, if it isn't within a table `Selection.Rows.Delete` must fail because rows can only be found if tables.

On the other hand, `Selection.Rows.Delete` must also fail because it is incorrect syntax which you seem to have borrowed from Excel. In Word you should first extend the selected range to include the entire row and then delete the range.

I realise that you seem to have a loop in mind which will perhaps read the items to be deleted from a list. That is much more complicated, but work on it can't be started until after your present code has been made to work. Therefore I suggest to focus on that target first.